# Raspberry Pi 3 A+ not detecting USB microphone running Ubuntu Server 23.04

Tags: sound, microphone

I hope the title speaks for itself.  I've got Ubuntu server version 23.04 on a Raspberry Pi 3 A+.  I plug a USB microphone into it and it isn't detected.  I'm running `arecord -l` and it's showing that there are no soundcards found.  I understand the A+ doesn't have a sound card, but I was under the impression that it doesn't matter with a USB mic.